# STS error while trying to run spring boot app on server

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

Here is the error (when I click on Run on Server):

```
Publishing the configuration...
Error copying file to E:/Softwares/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.1.RELEASE/base-instance/backup\catalina.policy: E:\Softwares\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.1.RELEASE\base-instance\conf\catalina.policy (The system cannot find the path specified)
E:\Softwares\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.1.RELEASE\base-instance\conf\catalina.policy (The system cannot find the path specified)
Error copying file to E:/Softwares/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.1.RELEASE/base-instance/backup\catalina.properties: E:\Softwares\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.1.RELEASE\base-instance\conf\catalina.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
E:\Softwares\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.1.RELEASE\base-instance\conf\catalina.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
Error copying file to E:/Softwares/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.1.RELEASE/base-instance/backup\context.xml: E:\Softwares\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.1.RELEASE\base-instance\conf\context.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
E:\Softwares\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.1.RELEASE\base-instance\conf\context.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
Error copying file to E:/Softwares/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.1.RELEASE/base-instance/backup\jmxremote.access: E:\Softwares\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.1.RELEASE\base-instance\conf\jmxremote.access (The system cannot find the path specified)
E:\Softwares\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.1.RELEASE\base-instance\conf\jmxremote.access (The system cannot find the path specified)
Error copying file to E:/Softwares/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.1.RELEASE/base-instance/backup\jmxremote.password: E:\Softwares\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.1.RELEASE\base-instance\conf\jmxremote.password (The system cannot find the path specified)
E:\Softwares\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.1.RELEASE\base-instance\conf\jmxremote.password (The system cannot find the path specified)
Error copying file to E:/Softwares/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.1.RELEASE/base-instance/backup\server.xml: E:\Softwares\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.1.RELEASE\base-instance\conf\server.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
E:\Softwares\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.1.RELEASE\base-instance\conf\server.xml (The system cannot
```

Comment: @Jen - I don't understand this. I believe this is a genuine issue that I am facing may be bacause of some upgrade. What's the reason for down vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your workspace is referencing server that doesn't exist anymore.

Just [delete](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwdelins.html) and [create new server](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwdelins.html) in STS. It is in "Servers" view.